# Python 2.x - How to work correctly with text in UNICODE

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode

Okay, I'm trying to manipulate a list of texts obtained through MongoDB. Here is how I can create a list and iterate only on the attribute that contains the messages:

```
client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
    db = client['...']
    query = {'message': {'$exists': 1}, 'id': {'$exists': 1}, 'created_time': {'$exists': 1}}
    projection = {'_id': 0, 'message': 1}

    db_messages = db['dadosColetados1'].find(query, projection)

    message_list=[]
    id_list=[]
    time_list = []
    for document in db_messages:
        for key, value in document.iteritems():
            if key == 'message':
                message_list.append(value)
                #print value
                word_final = status_processing(message_list)
            else:
                id_list.append(value)
                time_list.append(value)
     pair_up = zip(id_list, message_list, time_list)
```

What happens is the following, if I give a find in the mongo shell the text is returned to me correctly in Brazilian- Portuguese.

If in my code I put to print the `message_list` the text comes in this format: `e7\xf5es institucionais para uma seguran\xe7a p\xfablica`. If I put it to print what's inside `value` , 
The text comes correct. I need the list with the text to perform various operations that are within that function: `status_processing`. One of these involves the use of `BeautifulSoup`, but when it arrives at this stage BeautifulSoup shows me this exit: `declared_encoding_match = xml_encoding_re.search(markup, endpos=xml_endpos)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`.

Here is an example of how I make the process within the func `status_processing`

```
def status_processing(corpus):
    myCorpus = preprocessing.PreProcessing()
    myCorpus.text = message_list
    myCorpus.initial_processing()
```

And here's how I implemented my `BeautifulSoup`

```
 def initial_processing(self):
    #def __init__(self, text):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.text, "html.parser")
        #Todo Se quiser salvar os links mudar aqui
        self.text = re.sub(r'(http://|https://|www.)[^"\' ]+', " ", soup.get_text())
        self.tokens = self.tokenizing()
```

How to have the best approach in this situation? I transform to str through `myCorpus.text = str(message_list)` ? Vist I need to later get this text and store it again in the bank, this mode of conversion through `str ()` is not very good, the mongo warns that the type of `_id` created by it is wrong.

Comment: Do you know what encoding that string with the \x characters is in?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich When I put `print type (value)` it tells me it's in Unicode. 
And then I do the append in list `message_list.append(value)`